# How to nest anchor links via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, anchor

Looking for a great way to add anchor links within my HTML document after my pattern of H3 and the last p element block.

This is my original HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <h3 id="faqa">title</h3>
    <p>content</p>

    <h3 id="faqb">title</h3>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>

    <h3 id="faqc">title</h3>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>

    <h3 id="faqd">title</h3>
    <p>content</p>
</div>
```

And I want...

```
<div id="container">
    <h3 id="faqa">title</h3>
    <p>content</p>
    <p align="right"><a href="#">back to top</a>

    <h3 id="faqb">title</h3>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p align="right"><a href="#">back to top</a>

    <h3 id="faqc">title</h3>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p align="right"><a href="#">back to top</a>

    <h3 id="faqd">title</h3>
    <p>content</p>
    <p align="right"><a href="#">back to top</a>

</div>
```

Here is my honest effort so far, but no answer as of yet...

```
$("#container").each (function() {
     if($(this).find('h3[id*="faq"]')){
     var $mpage = window.location.pathname;
     $(this).find("p:last").append('<p align="right"><a href="'+$mpage+'">Back to top</a>
</p>'); 
}
});
```

The jQuery API has an excellent guide on prepend and append, but neither of them help me in this specific case.  Thanks for any light on the situation, I got about 40 of these anchors I have to add ;(

Thanks again for any help!

Comment: You're leaving a lot of open paragraph tags.

<p align="right"><a href="#">back to top</a>

You intend to close the tag immediately after the link right?

Comment: @ImportedNoob: The ID's are all different.

Comment: just noticed & deleted the comment before refreshing and noticing yours

Comment: my bad I forgot to close the <p> tags in my original post.  Yes they are closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var link = '<p align="right"><a href="#">back to top</a></p>';
$('#container h3').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('h3', 'p').last().after(link);
});
```

should do the trick.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/psvju/)

**Update:** karim's answer is nice and short <del>and you should go with this one</del> *Edit:* Apparently, as nice as the answer seems, it does not add a link to the last paragraph of the last heading.

I will still leave this answer here, as it shows a different way of approaching the problem.

karim's mindset basically is: Take every `h3` and add the link if it was preceded by a paragraph.

Mine was: Take every `h3` and find the last following paragraph (before the next `h3`) and append the link.

He thought upwards, I downwards ;)

Comment: thought about this again. in the case of the last p element that does  not have a h3 following it, this seems to make the most sense and tested it too.  you guys are amazing, thanks

Comment: @user: True, I have not thought about that. Good catch :)

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
$("#container h3").each(function() {
    if($(this).prev("p").length) {
        $(this).before("<p><a href='#'>fake link</a></p>");   
    }
});
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/nGx7b/1/)

EDIT based on our esteemed @Felix Kling's input:

```
$("h3").prev("p").after("<p><a href='#'>Back to top</a></p>");
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/nGx7b/2/)

Comment: `$(this).prev("p").after(....)` should work too (if you want to omit the `if`). +1 *Edit:* Then you might not even need the `each` loop: `$('h3').prev('p').after(...)`.

Comment: is it not beneficial to search for the faq pattern in my id names?

Comment: @user: Only if there are `h3` elements that should not be taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

```
//get all h3
var h3 = $("#container").find("h3[id^='faq']");

//store anchor html
var anchor = '<p align="right"><a href="#">back to top</a>';

//if h3 exist
if(h3.size()){
    // for every p before a h3 and the last p append anchor
    h3.prev("p").add("p:last").after(anchor);
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/TDSSd/